# SQL SELECT in JOIN last (maximum) row before the row with specific value

Tags: sql, select, db2

I have table T1:

```
TICKETID
1
2
3
```

I have table T2

```
ID  TICKETID  DESCRIPTION
1   1         First
2   2         Second
3   2         Automatic
```

I want to join those tables (SELECT must begin from T1 table) and to extract Last DESCRIPTION value before the Automatic value (for example because Automatic value is for TICKETID 2 it means last value before MAXIMUM ID (that is 3) and it means that value Second for TICKETID 2 should be extracted).
For TICKETID 1 and TICKETID since Automatic value does not exist it will have null  value.

So the final result should be

```
1 null
2 Second
3 null
```

I tried like this:

```
    select t11.ticketid, t21.description
    from t1 as t11
    left outer join t2 as t21 on t21.ticketid=t11.ticketid 
    left outer join
    (
    select t12.ticketid, max(t22.id) as maxwl from t2 as t22
    inner join t1 as t12 on t12.ticketid=t22.ticketid and t22.ticketid in 
    (select t23.ticketid from t2 as t23 inner join 
t1 as t13 on t13.ticketid=t23.ticketid and t23.description='Automatic')
    and t22.description!='Automatic'
    group by t12.ticketid
    ) as t24 on t22.maxwl=t21.id
```

Bu then I was getting as result:

```
1 First
2 Second
3 null
```

which is wrong because TICKETID 1 must have value Null because there is no description with value Automatic for it.

Comment: sorry mistake...it is corrected now.. it is value "Second"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be something like that. You just need to check two conditions before joining. But this is not very optimal as you read same table 3

```
select t11.ticketid, t21.description
from t1 as t11

left outer join 
    (   select * 
        from t2 as t22
        where exists 
            (   select max(t23.id) as maxid, t23.ticketid
                from t2 as t23
                where t23.description <> 'Automatic'
                    and t22.ticketid = t23.ticketid
                            and exists 
                            (   select max(t24.id) as max_aut_id, t24.ticketid
                                from t2 as t24 
                                where t24.description = 'Automatic' 
                                    and t23.ticketid = t24.ticketid
                                group by t24.ticketid
                                having t23.id < max_aut_id)
                group by t23.ticketid
                having maxid = t22.id)
    ) as t21 
    on t21.ticketid = t11.ticketid
```

Update: fixed so it would be the latest before Automatic, not just the latest non-automatic.

Comment: Hi Alex...please double check something is wrong... you have 4 these braces "(" and 5 these braces ")"

Comment: @Dejan is there any possibility that new description will be inserted after `Automatic` of the same ID? samething like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/96405/1

Comment: Hi, there is possibility that there can be multiple Automatic values for one TICKETID but we need last description before the last Automatic value... Thank you!

Comment: Yes, fixed. Everything is according to indentations :)

Answer (score 0):

Ohter method:

```
select t1.*, t4.description 
from t1                             
left outer join lateral                      
(                                            
   select * from t2                          
   where t1.TICKETID=t2.TICKETID             
   and t2.description='Automatic'            
   order by t2.id                            
   fetch first rows only                     
) t3 on 1=1 

left outer join lateral                      
(                                            
   select * from t2                          
   where t1.TICKETID=t2.TICKETID             
   and t2.id<t3.id                           
   and t2.description<>'Automatic'           
   order by t2.id desc                       
   fetch first rows only                     
) t4 on 1=1
```

Answer (score 0):

other method:

```
with t2withrang as (                                             
select t2.*, rownumber() over(                                   
partition by t2.TICKETID ,                                       
case when description ='Automatic' then 0 else 1 end             
order by t2.id desc ) rang,                                      
ifnull((select 1 from t2 t2b where t2.id<>t2b.id                 
and t2.TICKETID = t2b.TICKETID and t2b.description='Automatic'   
fetch first rows only )                                          
, 0) hasautomatic                                                
from t2                                                          
)                                                                
select t1.*, t3.description                                      
from t1 left outer join t2withrang t3                            
on t1.TICKETID=t3.TICKETID and t3.description<>'Automatic'       
and rang=1 and  hasautomatic=1
```